# Does it matter what direction a herringbone gear turns?

Tags: design, gears

Obviously, the forces and pressures should mostly be the same, but just in reverse. But when play, flex, and such are accounted for, are there any subtle differences to having a herringbone gear turn in different directions?

Intuitively, I might suspect that it would be preferable to turn towards the centerline, so that the first point of contact on each tooth isn't near either edge.

Comment: I've found a forum post where the pumping action on oil from rolling contact points was cited as a reason for mounting herringbone gears apex-first, which seems to make sense. That said, I don't know how credible it is, or whether there are other relevant considerations. https://www.practicalmachinist.com/vb/general/question-about-double-helix-gear-290343/

Comment: And if it turns clockwise, what direction does the gear in contact with it turn?

Comment: Assuming it's only rotating in one direction, I can see the apex-first style being preferable to prevent debris build up. If it's a two piece gear (2 opposing helicals) bound together, this would also force them together more which may be beneficial.

Comment: @jko Agreed on the debris point, but mostly speculatively. Not sure I totally agree with or understand the point about forcing them together— While the driving gear would be forced together, wouldn't the driven gear be forced apart by the same pressures?

Comment: @WillChen yes, while one gear would be forced "together" the opposing gear would be forced apart. If one of the gears is more prone to separation, I would imagine that would be the one oriented to be driven together. Example- small, one-piece pinion meshing with two separate helicals joined together. I would have the large gear be the apex first member.

Comment: @jko They would either both be apex-first, or both be root-first. You'd have to choose the direction depending on which gear is the driver, in order to control which one has inwards and which one has outwards pressures.

Comment: @WillChen yes, sorry. my previous comment was incorrect